# Multiply rows in a multi-index DataFrame by different rows in another multi-index DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have two large multi-index Dataframes, both look something like:

```
                               2000 2001 2002 2003 ...
Area AreaCode Item  Unit Code  
A    A1       one   j    00    val  val  val  val
              two   k    01    val  val  val  val
              three k    10    val  val  val  val
B    B1       one   j    00    val  val  val  val
              two   k    01    val  val  val  val
              three k    10    val  val  val  val
              four  k    10    val  val  val  val
C    C1       one   j    00    val  val  val  val
              two   k    01    val  val  val  val
              three k    10    val  val  val  val
```

where all the `val` are just floats.

I want to multiply each value in `df1` by the corresponding value in `df2`, divided by `np.sum(df2.xs("one", level = "Item"), axis = 1)` before using `.mean()`, which will give me a weighted mean. Something like:

```
for area in df1.index.get_level_values("Area"):
   df1[area] = (df1[area] * df2.xs("one", level = "Item").xs(area, level = "Area").values) \
               / np.sum(df2.xs("one", level = "Item"), axis = 1)
```

In my actual data, `df1` and `df2` have the same number of columns. `df1` contains per capita data and 
 `df2.xs("one", level = "Item")` is time series population data for each `Area`.

If there's an easy way to do this using `.mean()` I couldn't find one that allowed for a weighted mean.

I've also tried using `df1.multiply(df2.xs("one", level = "Item").xs(area, level = "Area"), level = "Area")` but I get `TypeError: cannot align on a multi-index with out specifying the join levels`.

I'm not tied to this method; if there's an easy way to get a weighted mean using `.mean()` I'd happily use it.

Comment: please provide a reproduceable example

Comment: @Thomas Ball, if you still need help with this, could you please provide a small sample of both df with real values? The easiest way is to do "df[:5].to_dict()" and copy/paste the resulting code into your question :)